# Simple grid design causing cls, Avoid major layout shifts cls

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple grid block with minimal css but it causes cls problem, The tags that are causing cumulative layout shift: h3, img, div, p, almost all of the block.

I tried to add more css to that tags but couldn't find a way to solve it.

First div is larger than other two divs and last two divs has same size

My codes are as follows:

```css
.grid-section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 48% 25% 25%);
  grid-gap: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.grid-section img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.grid-section h3 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.grid-section a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #0067b8;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.grid-section a:hover i {
  margin-left: 10px;
}


@media(max-width: 768px) {

  .grid-section {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }

  .grid-section :first-child {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 500px) {
  .grid-section {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="grid-section">
  <div>
    <img src="bvvvvvvvvvv/1.webp" class="img-fluid" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <h3>Save $150 + free controller</h3>
    <p>
      Buy an Xbox One X console and double your fun with a free select
      extra controller. Starting at $349.
    </p>
    <a href="#">Learn More <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="bvvvvvvvvvv/1.webp" class="img-fluid" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <h3>Save $150 + free controller</h3>
    <p>
      Buy an Xbox One X console and double your fun with a free select
      extra controller. Starting at $349.
    </p>
    <a href="#">Learn More <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="bvvvvvvvvvv/2.webp" class="img-fluid" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <h3>The new Microsoft Edge</h3>
    <p>
      Expect more. World class performance, with more privacy, more
      productivity, and more value.
    </p>
    <a href="#">Learn More <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @pierfarrugia I am creating a landing page that can publish articles with minimal css, grid does the job but its completley new for me. tags specified in question are moving their positing on mobile screen an causing cls problem. I thing I need to add more css to specify positions etc. for that tags.

Comment: first before anything else, for your media query to work you need to add in the head: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">. Do you have that? If not, put it, and tell me after...

Comment: Yes I have that. ```<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">``` nvm I have styled that tags and they are gone.

Comment: ok what do you mean by "tags". Here you have 1 section (grid, 3 columns 48 25 25% on big screen, 1fr 1fr on medium, 1fr on small), inside div first level will respond to grid defined. Inside each div you have 1 img, 1 title, text and an "a".

Comment: As I showed in question! ```<div>,<p>, <h1>, <img>``` html tags in ```<section>``` were causing cls, (because they were moving their position in small media screen).I had to add class to each html tags like: ```<h1 class="styled-class-name">``` and that solved the problem. actualy I wanted to create a block like in this template (the first block with slider). [bootnews][1][1]: https://demo.bootstrap.news/bootnews/html/home/ I couldnt. do that without bootstrap etc. with just grid, pure css. would be nice if you could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok with your demo, I better see what you are looking for.

simplest solution would be to use background image for the div which contain the image and the text. This solution already needs more structure in your html, but if you want to go with "img" tag, html structure will be at least 2 times more complex.

look at the snippet and try it in mobile view.

```css
.grid-section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 48% 25% 25%);
  grid-gap: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.grid-section>div {
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.grid-section .content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.grid-section h3 {}

.grid-section a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #0067b8;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.grid-section a:hover i {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .grid-section {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
  .grid-section :first-child {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .grid-section {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="grid-section">
  <div style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/20/800/600')">
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Save $150 + free controller</h3>
      <p>
        Buy an Xbox One X console and double your fun with a free select extra controller. Starting at $349.
      </p>
      <a href="#">Learn More <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/32/800/600')">
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Save $150 + free controller</h3>
      <p>
        Buy an Xbox One X console and double your fun with a free select extra controller. Starting at $349.
      </p>
      <a href="#">Learn More <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/43/800/600')">
    <div class="content">
      <h3>The new Microsoft Edge</h3>
      <p>
        Expect more. World class performance, with more privacy, more productivity, and more value.
      </p>
      <a href="#">Learn More <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Excelent, briliant, perfect :) more than what I wanted Thanks.

Comment: Jus for my knowledge! should I change this : ```.grid-section :first-child {``` to this ? or is it correct ? ```.grid-section div:first-child {``` in ```@media (max-width: 768px) {```

Comment: just :first-child is the first child whatever it is. div:first-child means the first div inside grid-section. In your case it's same, sometimes it's not. Could also be restricted like .grid-section > div:firstchild, here that means div first level only first child. Here in fact you have a second level div (content), but it's not a grid so this css don't apply